# Connecting to my SVN Repository using HTTPS

Tags: svn, https, apache2, ubuntu-12.04

I'm trying to set up my SVN server on Ubuntu 12.04 so that I can access it with HTTPS instead of HTTP that I'm using now.

I've tried to set it up with HTTPS, and it works with a local connection. I can also connect to it with my public IP address, when I'm in the house.

I've port-forwarded port number 443 to my server's local IP address, but when I try to connect to it from outside my house, it won't work.

I have OpenISS installed and configured with my Apache2 server. So my question is, is this fixable and do you need to see my setup files before you can help me? If so, just tell me and I will add it to the question!

Comment: @Sameer Please don't use backticks for emphasis but only for _code_, see e.g. [here](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/q/7437/88) why. You can also remove salutations while you're editing - "thanks" are implied by upvotes to answers

Comment: @TobiasKienzler Noted.

Comment: Thanks for advise, and editing! But i need an answer!! :/

Comment: You're going to need to provide more information to get any useful help here.  Saying that it doesn't work isn't specific enough.  What error message are you getting?  Can you connect to the server with a browser?

Comment: I can not connect to the server at all when i'm outside the house. So there is NO connection at all... there is no response in the browser. And it should be openSSL and not openISS.